# Google Cloud Endpoints V2 multi-class API error App Engine Standard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

**Error:** ApiConfigurationError: Attempting to implement service echo, version v2, with multiple classes that are not compatible. See docstring for api() for examples how to implement a multi-class API.

**Code:**

```
import logging
import endpoints
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote

class EchoRequest(messages.Message):
   content = messages.StringField(1)

class EchoResponse(messages.Message):
    content = messages.StringField(1)

ECHO_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    EchoRequest, n=messages.IntegerField(2, default=1))

@endpoints.api(name='echo', version='v1',description='description')
class EchoApi(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(
    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
    ECHO_RESOURCE,
    # This method returns an Echo message.
    EchoResponse,
    path='echo',
    http_method='POST',
    name='echo')

  def echo(self, request):
    logging.info("echo1"+ str(request.content))
    output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
    return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

@endpoints.api(name='echo', version='v2', description='description2')
class EchoApi2(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(
    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
    ECHO_RESOURCE,
    # This method returns an Echo message.
    EchoResponse,
    path='echo',
    http_method='POST',
    name='echo')

  def echo(self, request):
    logging.info("echo2" + str(request.content))
    output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
    return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

api = endpoints.api_server([EchoApi, EchoApi2])
```

GOOD if only: version='v1' (EchoApi)

ERROR if: version='v2' is added (EchoApi2)

ERROR CODE: ApiConfigurationError: Attempting to implement service echo, version v2, with multiple classes that are not compatible. See docstring for api() for examples how to implement a multi-class API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct format for creating an API implemented with multiple classes:

```
import logging
import endpoints
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote

class EchoRequest(messages.Message):
   content = messages.StringField(1)

class EchoResponse(messages.Message):
    content = messages.StringField(1)

ECHO_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    EchoRequest, n=messages.IntegerField(2, default=1))

echo_collection = endpoints.api(name='echo', version='v1', description='description')

@echo_collection.api_class(resource_name='echo1')
class EchoApi1(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(
    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
    ECHO_RESOURCE,
    # This method returns an Echo message.
    EchoResponse,
    path='echo',
    http_method='POST',
    name='echo')

  def echo(self, request):
    logging.info("echo1"+ str(request.content))
    output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
    return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

@echo_collection.api_class(resource_name='echo2')
class EchoApi2(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(
    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
    ECHO_RESOURCE,
    # This method returns an Echo message.
    EchoResponse,
    path='echo',
    http_method='POST',
    name='echo')

  def echo(self, request):
    logging.info("echo2" + str(request.content))
    output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
    return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

api = endpoints.api_server([echo_collection])
```

The documentation explains it: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/create_api#creating_an_api_implemented_with_multiple_classes